# __webpack_public_path__ in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I can't get the **webpack_public_path** to work with my vue application. i get this error:

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: '__webpack_public_path__' is not defined (no-undef) at src\publicpath.js:1:1:
> 1 | __webpack_public_path__ = process.env.VUE_APP_CHAT_URL;
    | ^
  2 |
```

heres how i have it implemented:

```
//publicpath.js
__webpack_public_path__ = process.env.VUE_APP_CHAT_URL;
```

and

```
//main.js
import './publicpath'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store/index'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  store
}).$mount('#tn-chat')
```

Is there something crucial i have left out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [no-def](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) ESLint rule is warning you about using an undeclared variable. You need to tell ESLint that `__webpack_public_path__` is a global variable.

You can [do it](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) using either a comment in the JS file where you are using it (`publicpath.js`), e.g.:

```
/* global __webpack_public_path__:writable */
```

Or in your ESLint config:

```
{
    "globals": {
        "__webpack_public_path__": "writable"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put a `/* eslint-disable */` block comment at the top of `publicpath.js`